# Help, I joined Sound Design as an AVP user, but some of my contributions aren't showing up

Tags: support, migration, avp-sound-merge

I recently signed up to Sound Design coming over from AVP after realizing that my posts were migrated here. Now that I'm here, I don't see some of my posts, but they've clearly been migrated to this site.

What can I do to get re-associated with the content that I've contributed?

Answer (score 3):

You should [contact the community team](https://sound.stackexchange.com/contact) and let them know. If you're not logged into the site, make sure you provide a link to your profile (just click on your avatar at the top of the page to find it) and (if possible) provide links to the posts that should be attached to your account.

Sometimes interesting things happen during migrations, which the community team can easily fix. We usually answer support requests within 24 hours of them being submitted, often sooner, so it won't be long before we can get it corrected for you (though, expect some delay late Fridays and over the weekend).

It's a fairly simple thing to fix. Don't worry - just drop us a line.

Comment: Your link to "contact the community team" just goes to sound.stackexchange.com - how do we actually contact the team?

Comment: @ObscureRobot Apologies, typing is apparently harder than I thought it was. Our contact form lives at `/contact` on every site, I just corrected the link.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link!